# Why are my google adsense impressions not more tightly correlated with page views?

Tags: google-adsense

My page views have been climbing steadily for about a year and a half:

[image]

But the number of impressions seems to go up and down with the wind. I have not made significant changes to the site in this time:

[image]

Is this expected/normal? It seems to me that there may be daily fluctuation in impressions, but I somehow would expect a tighter correlation with my page views, especially recently. Am I missing something?